# Можно ли вернуть результат функции НЕ promise, если внутри функции этот результат зависит от выполнения promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Например, в такой конструкции:

```
function someFunction (var) {
  let someVar = ''
  
  promiseFunction(var).then(answer => {
    someVar = ansver
  })

  return someVar
}
```

Или если в функции используется promise, то вся функция должна быть реализована в колбэке этого promise?

Comment: вроде нельзя...someFunction  будет async и в другой фукнкции, которая будет вызывать someFunction  придётся писать `console.log(await someFunction(1231);` и помечать функцию как async.  Вот так. Но это и не страшно... просто надо понимать зачем это нужно.

Comment: @Алексей-Шиманский, Получается, если есть цепочка функций, где одна вызывает другую, и только в самом конце цепочки async функция, то вся цепочка должна быть async?

Comment: Зависит от задачи. Если ни одной из них не нужен результат выполнения последней функции - нет, не надо всех асинкить))) Если же по цепочке снизу вверх пробрасывать значение, то скорее всего да. Но так никто не делает... Обычно сценарий проще: при клике вызывается комплексная функция, в которой нужно вызывать асинронную....тогда эта самая вызываемая будет помечена async и работать с await и вторая.....А хитровывернутых вложенных асинхронынх функций как правило не бывает

Comment: @Алексей-Шиманский, например, такой случай. Есть функция, она выводит на экран список ближайших рабочих дней из массива. Для этого она вызывает функцию, которая создаёт этот массив. Функция, заполняющая массив вызывает async функцию проверки дня (рабочий/не рабочий). Получается цепочка из трёх функций, в конце которого async проверка значения. Все три функции нужно делать async? Если это плохая архитектура, то как лучше реализовать задачу?

Comment: не совсем понял. вообще почему нельзя в одной функции `renderNearestWorkDays` сделать запрос на данные и затем передать при получении эти данные в метод `render(data)` а то и вовсе там же отрисовать.... просто эта цепочка получается ради цепочки....